# Android Referencing style attributes - triggering ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, resources, layout-inflater

I create my own style attribute like this:

```
 <attr name="color_foreground" format="color|reference" />
```

and I give it a value in my theme like that:

```
    <item name="color_foreground">@color/blue</item>
```

If i access this in my layout (that has been set as a contentView)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?color_foreground"
>
```

it works like a charme. But if I do the same in an inflated Layout I receive an error:

```
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myInflatedLayout, null);
```

the error Output:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010005 a=-1}
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1899)
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2810)
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:561)
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:554)
    06-27 20:33:37.340: E/AndroidRuntime(31616):    ... 48 more
```

Binary XML Line 15 is actually the line where i access the attr via "?color_foreground"

Nearly the same happens if I try to get the attribute like that (right after setting the content view) :

```
this.getResources().getColor(R.attr.color_foreground);
```

the error:

```
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f010005
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:749)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at ***.MyActivity.onCreate(AppointmentListActivity.java:66)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
06-28 12:55:16.975: E/AndroidRuntime(7089):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that I worked on the context of the activity. If I work on the activity itself it don't cause any problem.

Comment: Same problem for me.  I was getting my LayoutInflater from the application context instead of from the activity (which is an instance of context).

Answer (score 0):

> Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

From the looks of that exception, your custom attribute is not being recognised. You probably need to do one or both of the following:

1. Change the reference to `android:background="?attr/color_foreground"`.
2. In the `LinearLayout` definition, add a reference to the namespace that defines your custom attribute, which is just the package name of your project: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.package.name"`

My guess is that the first suggestion will be sufficient, but just in case, you may like to try the second too.

Comment: nope, didn't work - I assume there is something wrong with the context since programmatically calling attr don't work as well (I will update my question).

Answer (score -1):

In case someone might encounter this problem again. Change

```
android:background="?color_foreground"
```

to

```
style="?color_foreground"
```

and in theme you can specify (if you have multiple themes, you will add this one by one in every theme, but different color/style, depends on your design)

```
<item name="color_foreground">@color/blue</item>
```

or

```
<item name="color_foreground">@style/blue</item>
```

and in your style

```
<style name="blue">
    <item name="android:background">#0000FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103894/overriding-referenced-style-attributes